# AVD problem with contentObserver

Tags: java, android

is that work in `AVD 2.2` for retrieve phone number?

```
Cursor sms_sent_cursor = SMSObserver4.this.managedQuery(
    Uri.parse("content://sms"), null, "type=?", new String[] { "2" }, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work on a real mobile? If yes, try installing the Google API and create an 2.2 AVD based on that. Because it *may* be caused by using a service/feature that's ony available from the addon.

Comment: i m just getting the SMS number nothing else